# Markov Chain: flip coin 8 times and get 3 consecutive heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have confusion while reading the following example in the course material.

Q: In a sequence of independent flips of a fair coin, let N denote the
number of flips until there is a run of three consecutive heads. Find

(a) $P(N \leq8)$

and
(b) $P(N = 8)$.

---

For part b), the solution is given by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608573/markov-chain-flip-8-coins-and-get-3-consecutive-heads). 
However, I am confused about the solution for part a). The solution is given by below:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

---

**Confusion:**

I guess the source of confusion is because I don't understand the setup of this problem (in particular, the absorbing state=3). Most importantly, I don't understand how $P(X_{8}=3)$ will give $P(N\leq8)=P(N=1)+P(N=2)+...+P(N=8).$  It is possible that the state reaches 3 in any $N=6$ (as shown by the picture below).

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

One additional question, can I say $P(N\leq8)$ is the probability  of getting a run of three consecutive heads in 8 flips (in the original question, it is asking the probability of getting 3 heads **until** N number of flips)?

Comment: $X_8$ is the state after $8$ tosses.  Any time you reach state $3$, you stay in state $3$ from then on.  So if you reach state $3$ after six tosses, you stay there for the seventh and eighth tosses.

Comment: I guess my question is, what does it even mean for staying at state 3 for 7th and 8th tosses? Is the game already over at the 6th tosses?

Comment: They have tweaked the game.  "Toss 8 coins and check if you had 3 in a row" and "Toss at most 8 coins, stop if you get 3 in a row" have the same probability of winning.

Comment: So I guess, $X_8=3$ already includes that you reach state 3 when N=3, N=4, N=5, N=6, N=7, and N=8?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have got 3 consecutive heads, your goal is attained, and the task is over.

1.The probabilities in question obtained after N trials are the **cumulative** probabilities.
2. No, you can't say that. $P(N \le 8)$  is the probability that **at most** $8$ flips are needed.

you can understand from the probability values for trials 3 through 8

$3\quad  0.125 000 000$
$4\quad  0.187 500 000$
$5\quad  0.250 000 000$
$6\quad  0.312 500 000$
$7\quad  0.367 187 500$
$8\quad  0.417 968 750$

Comment: I have thought it over and found my source of confusion. In my diagram (the x-y plot) above, at the 6th step, we reach state 3. And we stay in state 3 for step 7 and step 8. What does that even mean?

Comment: It means that you have **already achieved** 3 successive heads, and so once in that "state", you "stay" there.

Comment: So I guess, $X_8=3$ already includes that you reach state 3 when N=3, N=4, N=5, N=6, N=7, N=8.

Comment: Yea, that's what I said, it is cumulative probability.