# Coin flipping to get consecutive heads (large number version)

Tags: probability

I flip a fair coin 10^9 times, what's the probability of having observed a sequence of 100 consecutive heads?

Having read and understand [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610383/markov-chain-flip-coin-8-times-and-get-3-consecutive-heads), I've learned to use Markov chain to solve related problem with small sizes. Nevertheless, the method consumes long runtime when the number of flipping and the requirement of consecutive heads get large. Is there some other methods to compute exact probability, or some good approximations?

Answer (score 1):

Since the probability for one such occurrence is alredy very low, you can disregard the possibility of two separate occurrences (where "separate" means "separated by at least one tails"). Then the probability for at least one occurrence is approximately the expected number of separate occurrences. Each separate occurrence has one occurrence of a tails followed by $100$ heads, and there are about $10^9$ places where this can occur. Thus the probability is approximately

$$
10^9\cdot2^{-101}\approx4\cdot10^{-22}\;.
$$