# Flip a coin 10 times, probability that no face shows up three times in a row?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

Given a fair coin, if we flip the coin $10$ times, what is the probability that the string of flips does not contain a $'HHH'$ or $'TTT'$ anywhere inside it?

That is, what is the probability that neither heads or tails shows up three times in a row? (As the title suggests)

---

Total number of outcomes: $2^{10}$

From seeing related posts and doing some googling, it seems a recurrence relation can be used to solve a problem of this sort, but I got stuck. I don't know if there is another way to solve this kind of problem. (Besides brute force of counting the outcomes we desire) [The answer given to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630656/flip-a-coin-5-times-what-is-the-probability-that-heads-never-occurs-twice-in-a) by N.F Taussig gave me a good start to setting up the problem, but their answer deals with the stipulation that only heads doesn't show up twice in a row.

Letting $a_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ that do not have $3$ consecutive heads or tails in them.

It is relatively straightforward to see that $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 4$, and $a_3 = 6$

If our sequence of length $n$ ends with $HH$, it must have a $T$ in the $n-2$ position.

If our sequence ends with $TT$, it must have a $H$ in the $n-2$ position.

I am unsure of how to go on from here.

---

I would also be interested in generalizing this process to $N$ flips of a fair coin where neither heads or tails shows up $k$ times in a row. ($k \ge 2$)

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: "I don't know if there is another way to solve this kind of problem.": Markov chains: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608573/markov-chain-flip-8-coins-and-get-3-consecutive-heads?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is coupled recurrence relations.  Let $b_n$ be the number of $n$ length sequences that end in one of the same letter, so they end in HT or TH (or are length $1$), and $c_n$ be the number of $n$ length sequences that end in two of the same, so HH or TT.  We then have $$a_n=b_n+c_n\\b_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}\\c_n=b_{n-1}\\b_1=2\\b_2=2\\c_1=0\\c_2=2$$
where the $b_n$ comes because we can we can put the other flip after any series and the $c_n$ comes because we can put another on if there is only one at the end so far.  This gives $$b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$$ so $b_n$ is just twice the Fibonacci numbers and $c_n$ is twice the Fibonacci numbers offset by $1$.
$$b_n=2F_n\\c_n=2F_{n-1}\\a_n=2F_n+2F_{n-1}=2F_{n+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does help me understand the case for not allowing three of either face to show up in a row.  It appears that one could also generalize this method for not allowing a face to show up $k$ times in a row if we add in more sequences? (For example when $k=4$, we use four sequences $a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n$?)

Comment: Using the similar process you described above (with $d_n$ being sequences that end with three of the same), would the sequences for the case of $k=4$ be: $$a_n = b_n+c_n+d_n$$ $$b_n = b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} + d_{n-1}$$ $$c_n = b_{n-1}$$ $$d_n = c_{n-1}$$ I just want to see if I am understanding the process correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.